# Laravel form validation using where clause

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a small project using Laravel and everything is ok with me just i would like to know how can i add a where clause in my validation rule this my code :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'number' => 'required|integer|unique:apartments,number',
    ];
}
```

i have a table called peoples, contain 3 fields `(id, number, room)`

```
how i can add a where clause including room field,  where number is  unique and room != 5,
```

Comment: which laravel version are we talking about here?

Comment: Can you clarify the end of your question a bit? Also, if you could provide an example you would expect to fail validation, and pass validation please, it would help us out greatly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using Laravel 7 you can handle it like this

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'number' => [
            'required',
            'integer',
            Rule::unique('apartments', 'number')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('room', '!=', 5);
            })
        ]
    ];
}
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: can i replace number 5 by a variable ? since i'm using a form

Comment: Yes just refactor the code to have access to the variable and then pass it to where like `function ($query) use ($roomNumber) {`

Comment: like that ? return $query->where('room', '!=',  $roomNumber);

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
public function rules()
{
return [
    'number' => [
        'required',
        'integer',
        Rule::unique('apartments')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('room', '!=', 5);
        })
    ]
];
}
```